# Dataweave Transformation- How can I reduce a payload array when condition is met

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

I have this JSON payload:

```
[
    {
        "Id": "6812",
        "status": "Available",
        "expirationDate": "2024-04-30T13:00:00.000-07:00",
        "quantityOnHand": 6124
    },
    {
        "Id": "7491",
        "status": "Available",
        "expirationDate": "2024-06-29T13:00:00.000-07:00",
        "quantityOnHand": 864
    },
    {
        "NetsuiteId": "6569",
        "status": "Available",
        "expirationDate": "2100-12-12T13:00:00.000-07:00",
        "quantityOnHand": 3

    },
    {
        "Id": "6582",
        "status": "Available",
        "expirationDate": "2100-12-12T13:00:00.000-07:00",
        "quantityOnHand": 1
    }
]
```

I have a variable component that sets my order quantity. Basically what I want to do is return the payload items that will suffice the order quantity variable. So for example my vars.quantityOrder is 100, then my transform component will return :

```
{
        "Id": "6812",
        "status": "Available",
        "expirationDate": "2024-04-30T13:00:00.000-07:00",
        "quantityOnHand": 6124
    }
```

If it is 6500 , then it would return :

```
[
    {
        "Id": "6812",
        "status": "Available",
        "expirationDate": "2024-04-30T13:00:00.000-07:00",
        "quantityOnHand": 6124
    },
    {
        "Id": "7491",
        "status": "Available",
        "expirationDate": "2024-06-29T13:00:00.000-07:00",
        "quantityOnHand": 864
    }
]
```

And so on.

I am very new to DataWeave and I'm not sure how I can do this. I have written up something like:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json

var quantityOrder = vars.quantityOrder 

var result = payload filter ((item, index) -> quantityOrder > 0) map ((item, index) -> {
    "Id": item.Id,
    "status": item.status,
    "expirationDate": item.expirationDate,
    "quantity": item.quantityOnHand - quantityOrder

})

---
result
```

However this gives me syntax errors. Would appreciate any guidance or input.

Comment: The example with 6500 makes no sense. What are you comparing exactly? Be more clear and specific.

Comment: It’s hard to tell exactly what issue are you having. See the [How to Ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help clarifying this question. Include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the issue. See also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also note that the code format delimiter (the three backticks should be in a line by itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear what is the issue you are having but if you are trying to get the items from the input payload where `quantityOnHand > quantityOrder` then the condition of your filter is incorrect. I would change it to:

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json

var quantityOrder = 100

var result = payload 
    filter ((item, index) -> item.quantityOnHand > quantityOrder) 
    map ((item, index) -> 
        {
            "Id": item.Id,
            "status": item.status,
            "expirationDate": item.expirationDate,
            "quantity": item.quantityOnHand - quantityOrder
        }
    )
---
result
```

The output for your input payload is:

```json
[
  {
    "Id": "6812",
    "status": "Available",
    "expirationDate": "2024-04-30T13:00:00.000-07:00",
    "quantity": 6024
  },
  {
    "Id": "7491",
    "status": "Available",
    "expirationDate": "2024-06-29T13:00:00.000-07:00",
    "quantity": 764
  }
]
```

Comment: Thank you so much Aled, I am still new to stackoverflow. I'll be sure to check the How to ask page. I do apologize that my question does not make sense. Your answer is greatly appreciated and its very close to what I need to do.

Comment: Please don't ask additional questions in comments. You can post a new question with all the details and examples.